# error when zoom to max with PhotoViewAttacher android

Tags: android

I used PhotoViewAttacher to zoom in and out in image view android, 
it's working but when zoom in to the max or zoom out, the app crashes

this is my code:

```
    ImageView image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    try {
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(myList.get(position).getImg()).error(R.mipmap.load_images).placeholder(R.mipmap.load_images).into(image);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        mAttacher= new PhotoViewAttacher(image);
        mAttacher.update();
        container.addView(itemView);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the known issues [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView#issues-with-viewgroups)?

Maybe that is the case:

> This is a framework issue that has not been resolved. In order to
>   prevent this exception (which typically occurs when you zoom out),
>   take a look at **HackyDrawerLayout** and you can see the solution is to
>   simply catch the exception.

```
public class HackyProblematicViewGroup extends ProblematicViewGroup {

public HackyProblematicViewGroup(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    try {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    //uncomment if you really want to see these errors
        //e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

}